# Executable lauches if called directly from terminal, but does not work when called from shell script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I have downloaded some software (called `samtools`) and it is stored in a folder on my desktop. 
Then I've added the path to the executable into the `PATH` environment variable.
In other words my `~/.bashrc` file has the following line:

```
export PATH="~/Desktop/samtools/samtools-1.1:$PATH".
```

The executable file named `samtools` is in this folder.

When I try to launch it from the command line by simply typing `samtools`, it works. It also works when I use the full path to the executable.

However, when I try to launch it from a shell script, it does not launch and reports either:
`No such file` or `Directory not found`.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

EDIT:
As some people requested.

The exact error message is:

```
Realigning using Bowtie2...
./RP_capture//realign/filter_long_inserts.sh: 29: ./RP_capture//realign/filter_long_inserts.sh: samtools: not found
./RP_capture//realign/filter_long_inserts.sh: 29: ./RP_capture//realign/filter_long_inserts.sh: samtools: not found
Could not locate a Bowtie index corresponding to basename "./aux/chr1.fa"
```

I have also added `echo $PATH` to my script and the output seems correct. Path to samtools is there.

this is example of one of many calls to samtools from the script.

```
samtools index $OUTPUT/realignments/$file.abnormal.realign.bowtie.bam
```

I have actually managed to solve the problem using

```
export set SAMTOOLS_DIR="/home/laba/Desktop/samtools/samtools-1.1"
```

within a script and then calling samtools like this:

```
$SAMTOOLS_DIR/samtools [parameters]
```

Strangely enough, another binary script calls works with just explicitly providing path to the executable. Without having to use `set`.

Comment: Please edit your question and insert a copy/paste of the relevant part(s) of your script.

Comment: I have edited my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting directory variable like this:

```
export set SAMTOOLS_DIR="/home/laba/Desktop/samtools/samtools-1.1"
```

And then calling the exacutable from the script like this:

```
$SAMTOOLS_DIR/samtools [parameters]
```

solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a echo $ PATH in the script, to ensure the path is what you think it is,  and ensure the script itself can run (executable bit set, correct shebang #!/bin/sh or whatever in the first line). If nothing else works, you may try stracing the script invocation call.

## Update

From the error message, it is clear that the problem arises in a sub-script, which invokes `samtools` on its own:

> ./RP_capture//realign/filter_long_inserts.sh at line 29

So the problem is *that* invocation of `samtools`, which is either missing a `PATH` or some other variable component.

As you found out, that component is in all likelihood `SAMTOOLS_DIR`.

Another possibility worth investigation is that the problem is in the **user** running the script (e.g. via `sudo` or the like). In that case, the value of `PATH` set to "~/Desktop...", where the "~" means "The home user of the *current user*", would end up meaning two different things for you and for the user running the script. In that case you ought to set PATH to

```
/home/laba/Desktop/samtools/samtools-1.1:$PATH
```

instead of

~/Desktop/samtools/samtools-1.1:$PATH

Comment: I have added echo $PATH to the script and it seems good. Path to samtools is there. Also I've changed shebang from #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash. Which was the output of 'which bash' command.