# How to block shell script from being called elsewhere other than the folder it is on?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, shell-script

I would like to halt my shell script if the user is currently not the shell script directory. For example, I am on the folder `~/` and call the shell script `~/shell/script.sh`, the shell script should print `You are not allowed to call this shell script from another folder other than its directory`. But if I am on the folder `~/shell` and call `./script.sh` than the execution is allowed.

> Why do you care what the `$PWD` is? You can change directories in the script if it matters: `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`

It is a very local aggressive/dangerous script, so I would like the user to be present on the folder paying more attention on it when it is running the script.

---

Related questions:

1. [Check if bash script was invoked from a shell or another script/application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261876/check-if-bash-script-was-invoked-from-a-shell-or-another-script-application)
2. [Executable lauches if called directly from terminal, but does not work when called from shell script](https://superuser.com/questions/856759/executable-lauches-if-called-directly-from-terminal-but-does-not-work-when-call)

Comment: Your own question already answers this in the 2nd paragraph – you can compare `$PWD`.

Comment: Second paragraph is a comment from [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45532163/3776858).

Comment: See: [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/3776858)

Comment: Why don't you just have the script change directory to its own directory? Then it doesn't matter where you call it from: `cd "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"`

Comment: Because I need to ensure the `$0` contains the current file file on the form `./shell.sh`, as later on the shell script, I am using `find .` to list the files on the current folder and with `"$path" != "$0"`  is how I choose to exclude the own shell script from this processing list I am applying `sed .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full path to your executing script by using `realpath` to resolve the implicit current directory (`man realpath` for details, the `-P` option can be useful):

```
mydir=$(dirname $(realpath $0))
[[ $PWD != $mydir ]] && { echo "Not in the right directory!"; exit 1; }
echo "OK, proceed..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @grawity, I wrote this:

```
# Call the main function, as when running from the command line the `$0` variable is 
# not empty.
#
# Importing functions from a shell script
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815774/importing-functions-from-a-shell-script
if ! [[ -z "$0" ]]
then
    # Reliable way for a bash script to get the full path to itself?
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get
    pushd `dirname $0` > /dev/null
    SCRIPT_FOLDER_PATH=`pwd`
    popd > /dev/null

    if[[ "$SCRIPT_FOLDER_PATH" == "$(pwd)" || "$SCRIPT_FOLDER_PATH" == "$(dirname "$0")" ]]
    then
        main "$@"
    else
        printf "You cannot run this from the folder: \n'$(pwd)'\n"
        printf "\nPlease, run this script from its folder on: \n'$SCRIPT_FOLDER_PATH'\n"
    fi
fi
```